# ClassCastException running Applet after update to JRE 7u21

Tags: java, applet, classcastexception

I'm working on a signed Applet that will no longer start under version 7u21 of the JRE.

I've recompiled the applet using the 7u21 JDK, I've added the `Trusted-Library:true` line to the manifest (and removed it again after it caused a SecurityException), I've reinstalled the JRE. Here's what I could get out of the Java console:

```
basic: exception: com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine$2 cannot be cast to com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.  
ExitException[ 3]java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine$2 cannot be cast to com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry  
               at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)  
               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)  
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The applet is being deployed using Oracle's deployJava script.

This is happening on all our test systems in Chrome, FireFox, IE 8 and 9, which would point to a plugin problem. It's currently impacting a production system that's been running just fine for over a year before this JRE update.

Any insight anyone has would be greatly appreciated.

The JNLP file content from a local build is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" version="2.0.30" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="avs/res/util-applet.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Utility Applet - LOCAL</title>
        <vendor>Vendor</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m"/>
        <jar href="/avs/res/util-jar-with-dependencies.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <applet-desc name="guiApplet" main-class="au.edu.ncver.avs.web.util.UtilApplet" width="1" height="1"/>
    <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

**Update 1**
I can pretty well confirm that this is coming from the plugin's cache. If I go into the Java Control Panel and disable local storage, then the problem goes away. Re-enabling local storage brings the problem back.

**Update 2**
Updated the JNLP to reflect a fix to the aforementioned SecurityException; but the ClassCastException remains. I've logged a bug with Oracle a few weeks ago but have heard nothing from them, nor has the bug actually appeared in their database.

**Update 3**
Problem still exists in 7u25.

Comment: Can you post your JNLP file as well? what is jre version specified and what is its href?

Comment: I've added the JNLP file from a local build for reference -- unfortunately the whole thing is behind an authentication layer for providing a direct URL to the production code isn't viable.